# NodeJS Forge viewer error on Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, autodesk-forge

I've deployed my Forge viewer app based on the *View BIM 360 & Fusion models* tutorial, and I'm having trouble with authentication on Google App Engine.

Having set my callback URL to https://forgeviewer-218710.appspot.com/api/forge/oauth/token, the autentication does not work.

Is this because I need to set my ID, secret, & callback URL in the app.yaml file that App Engine uses to deploy? Or am I way off track?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried run your app, but got `Error : 400 - Invalid redirect_uri`, which means that the Callback URL on the Developer Portal is different from the one your specified on your app.

On the tutorial, at [Create an app](http://learnforge.autodesk.io/#/account/?id=create-an-app) section, we use `http://localhost:3000/api/forge/callback/oauth`, but when creating the Forge app that you'll use on your live app, you should use the live version, in this case `https://forgeviewer-218710.appspot.com/api/forge/callback/oauth` (which is different from what you specified on your question, so please adjust).

To summarize, the callback url **MUST** match on Forge app registration and on your app live (assuming you have Nodejs, on the `FORGE_CALLBACK_URL` environment variable). Sorry I don't have experience deploying to Google App Engine.